# why is Inline SQL a bad thing to include in an application

Tags: c#, c++, sql, sql-server

I have been doing some research on SQL to boost my knowledge on the topic, I have came across quite a few people saying that Inline SQL is a bad thing but no one is saying why, I was hoping someone could help me to understand; Why inline SQL within an application (Such as c#) is a bad thing, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "inline SQL"? Dynamically generated?

Comment: Please try to do as much research on your part and then ask question.
Also, for asking question in Stackoverflow, you may refer this ( http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ ) link.
Thanks!

Comment: Most of the people answering your question so far seem to be focusing on other issues.  However, inline SQL also tends to be worse for performance than a view, function, or stored procedure.  In general, the database engine will have a better chance of optimizing the execution for these sort of re-usable objects than some query that is just passed to it as a string. In some cases the performance difference can be very significant.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is bad practise to use in-line query

- Hackers can **modify** your query.
- **SQL Injection** can attempt by users
- If there is even small change in query you have to **publish whole application**.
- For long query statement, it **hard to read**.
- You **can't reuse** query statement, like View, Function are used in SQL Server

Look more at [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1818517.aspx?Inline%20Queries%20Vs%20Store%20Procedure).

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot.

Comment: In regards to SQL Injection, you are confusing inline and dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL can occur in stored procs and be vulnerable to SQL injection.  Inline SQL which is not dynamic SQL is not vulnerable to injection.